# WorkManager обратная связь из задачи

Tags: java, android

WorkManager.
У меня продолжительная по времени задача, передача порядка сотен файлов на сервер.
Я думал создам задачу и пусть WorkManager пересылает данные когда можно.

И встал вопрос с обратной связью, например узнать сколько уже передано.
Т.е. не по факту выполнения задачи, а на текущий момент.
Возможно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Если для каждого файла создать задачу на передачу, то в WorkManager при старте или планировании задачи можно передать слушателя (WorkListener).
В методе WorkListener.workCompleted увеличивать счетчик обработанных задач в контексте, видимом с нужных мест. Зная общее количество задач и количество выполненных, можно легко определить прогресс.

Если все делаешь в одной задаче, то в ней надо надо самому определить точки прогресса (например после передачи очередного файла в цикле) и также инкрементить счетчик в передаваемом контексте.

Например для второго случая:

```
Worker {
  private final AtomicInteger counter;

  public Worker(AtomicInteger counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
  }

  public run() {
    for (... цикл по файлам) {
      ... пересылаем файл
      counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Немного не в тему: WorkManager позволяет формировать задачи, которые вне основного потока и приложения будут выполняться. Что будет, если задача в WorkManager-е висит, а приложение удалили. Останется?